# Which is better solution get server response data?

Tags: android, inputstream, inputstreamreader

We usually get data from server response in android development.

```
/*
* get server response inputStream
*/
InputStream responseInputStream;
```

Solution1: get response string by multiple read.

```
      /*
       * get server response string
      */
    StringBuffer responseString = new StringBuffer();
    responseInputStream = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");

    char[] charBuffer = new char[bufferSize];
    int _postion = 0;
    while ((_postion=responseInputStream.read(charBuffer)) > -1) {
        responseString.append(charBuffer,0,_postion);
        }
    responseInputStream.close();
```

Solution2: get response only one read.

```
String responseString = null;
int content_length=1024;
// we can get content length from response header, here assign 1024 for simple.
responseInputStream = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");

char[] charBuffer = new char[content_length];
int _postion = 0;
int position = responseInputStream.read(charBuffer)
if(position>-1){
   responseString = new String(charBuffer,0,position );
 }
responseInputStream.close();
```

Which solution has better performance? why?

**Notes**: server response json format data that less than 1M bytes.

Comment: the second one is much faster

Comment: I tend to use the first solution because then I know for sure the buffer size, which is a valid point mostly if you don't treat the result as a String.

Comment: @njzk2  you recommend the solution2?

Comment: one point on the second solution is that you don't check the actually read length, and you don't have a mechanism in case it is not fully read.

Comment: Also, for simplicity, with a broader choice, i tend to use EntityUtils.toString, given that I use HttpClient. Looking at the code, it does basically the first solution (but it is bundled)

Comment: @njzk2 ,Instinct tell me that solution1 is better. But i do not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you're reinventing a wheel? ;)

If you're using HttpClient then just use `EntityUtils.toString(...)`.
I guess you're using `HttpURLConnection`. Then look at `EntityUtils.toString(...)` from Apache HttpClient - [source code](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.java.html). Your first approach is similar to it.

BTW, the second code is worse because:

`new String(charBuffer,0,position )` runs garbage collector

In both and even in EntityUtils:

`int content_length = 1024;` in most cases 8192 is default for socket buffer, so your code might run while loop 8 times more often than it could.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the **second** method IF you do **not** want to display the amount of data  downloaded/transferred . As the object is read as a whole and since the size of your JSON string is comparable to 1M, it will take some time to download. At that time you can, atmost, put up a text for the user saying **downloading..**. You cannot notify the user the amount downloaded.
But if you want to display the amount of data downloaded, use the **first** method that you gave. Where the you read the data from the server in parts. You can update the *UI*, with the amount downloaded.  For eg **25 % downloaded...**

```
char[] charBuffer = new char[bufferSize];
    int _postion = 0;
    int i=0;
    while ((_postion=responseInputStream.read(charBuffer)) > -1) {

       //((i*buffer_size)/content_length) * 100  % completed..

        i++;
        }
```

So, I would say the seconds method is better.

BTW Did you consider this?

```
ObjectInputStream in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");
if(resposeCode==200)
{
 String from_server=(String)  in.readObject();
}
```

Reading the input String as an object. Any object whoe class implements serializable can be passed using `ObjectOutputStream`  and received using `ObjectInputStream()`

Comment: regardless the response code. My question is key concern get response data only one read or multiple read.

Comment: @boiledwater : yeah ObjectInputStream, reads data in one go. You do not have to worry about the length  and all. and you can transfer any object whose class implements serializable. The response code was no the point here.

Comment: Which solution you recommend? and why?

Answer (score 0):

I Think **First one is good**

Because, in **First**  that will reading your response in char to char method .

Where , **Second**  that will try to read whole response object or as key Filed of Object.

So ,As i think and as per my knowledge First is Better to camper with second.If anyone want to edit then it will truly appreciated.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean regarding the second ?

Comment: that will trying to read whole key obj. like in in compiler that will not stop until whole program not be compiled and in interposition that interprate  statement by statement. get it >